# How can I edit/share the same text file from my Linux laptop (code editor or command line) and my iPhone?

Tags: linux, file-management, command-line, file-synchronization, iphone-app

The only way to edit the same file on iPhone and (Linux) laptop that I can find is Google Drive. However, on laptop Google docs don't have code syntax colouring / highlighting. Also with Google docs iPhone you can't make a Home screen link that takes you straight to a file, so it's slightly inconvenient.

I was wondering whether there's an even better solution for this, such as a text editor (internet or notepad app) which has an iPhone app and can colour code?

EDIT1: I'm not rich so am looking for a free or one-time payment / cheap option

EDIT2: https://workingcopyapp.com/ seems to solve my problems since I could then just use my text editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want, but still...

It's not an IDE, and this works only for turning on highlighting for code *snippets* embedded in another textfile:

I think you can use [Joplin](https://github.com/laurent22/joplin) or the [App](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/joplin/id1315599797) which is an Evernote clone with a few differences:

- You write Markdown files
- The synchronization backend is your choice

Inside the markdown files you can denote a code block with "`````" markers. So for a SQL block can you write ```js and then the editor activates its internal Javascript syntax highlighting.

I don't know how good the syntax highlighters for the respective languages are though.

The tool and the App are free, and both are under active development.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for something exactly like this (and also not averse to a new text editor). Think it said on the docs that you can use it with Sublime, I'm not sure how this would work since I thought it was a text editor itself. Will give it a try and also report on the syntax highlighting!

Answer (score 0):

[Code Anywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/apps#android) should work. It has an IOS and Web client and supports syntax highlighting plus many other features typically found in an IDE. Additionally, you can setup the file you want to be edited on Google Drive or an ftp server and use Code Anywhere to edit it from there.

Comment: thanks but looks a bit too expensive, I may go broke one day and can't afford the monthly fee

Comment: @MilanLakhani You didn't specify that it had to be free, but if you're a student or work at a university they supposedly have free/discounted plans available.

Comment: I wouldn't mind paying like £40 as a one off but even the cheapest which was like £5 a month for lifetime doesn't work for me. Thanks for the answer though